# Show android dialogs in sequence

Tags: android, dialog

In my app some dialogs are opened from different places at the same time. (Some dialogs are self build fragments others AlertDialogs) This causes some of them to disappear, because the last called dialog closes all previously opened ones.

Is there a nice way to make them queue up and show after each other instead of glitch out like that?

I was considering making my own dialog class which instead of disposing the dialog it load up the next one and disposes once none are left in the queue. I am hoping there is an easier way to solve my problem without so much effort behind it.

Comment: Are you using an AlertDialog constructed with an AlertDialog.Builder or are you extending DialogFragment?

Comment: To the point of @Dziugas. Could you please just post some code associated with your current issue. If we had code to look at we would not need to ask clarifying questions and you will get more traction on your question.

Comment: @Dziugas both are used

Comment: @doubleA Clarified his question in my post. Don't see how code would help here since it's simply multiple Dialogs opened by different fragments at the same time. Situation doesn't get much more complex :o

Comment: @Basti you may think its simple and not too complex... or you might be overlooking something... if you knew the answer you would not be here. what I know for sure is that code never lies and is always helpful in clarifying a problem domain especially on SO. So for the good of the community please get in a habit of posting relevant code. Everything not relating to your specific code that you did not post is just a guess.

Comment: Might have been useful to post code that you have already tried and problems you had implementing so the person did not need to waste time giving an answer that you already had issues implementing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try a solution that your very own question hinted at; a queue.  This solution should work with any dialogs which extend the `Dialog` class.

To do so add a `Dialog` queue to your activity as a global variable:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Dialog> dialogsToShow = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
```

In addition to the above, implement, in the Activity that wants to show the dialogs, a method called `showDialog()` which accepts the target dialog as a parameter.  This method will add the dialog to the queue and also ensure that the dialog calls the next one in the queue to be shown after it is dismissed.

```
void showDialog(final Dialog dialog) {
        if(dialogsToShow.isEmpty()) {
            dialog.show();
        }
        dialogsToShow.offer(dialog);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener((d) -> {
            dialogsToShow.remove(dialog);
            if(!dialogsToShow.isEmpty()) {
                dialogsToShow.peek().show();
            }
        }); 
}
```

Please note that I didn't test the above code.

Comment: You forgot to open a new Dialog in case the queue isn't empty, but nice approach :)

Comment: Thanks @Basti.  I think there's no need because whenever the first dialog is dismissed it will show the next dialog in the queue before it removes itself.

Comment: Also, the listener should have been set on dialog, not dialogsToShow. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Yea true, my bad. Brainfart :D

Comment: @Dziugas: can we similarly add DialogFragments in a queue ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to implement your own implementation of `Dialog` here in this case as far as I have understood. You just have to maintain your own queue data structure in sqlite database or somewhere else. When a dialog is popped up, show the first one from your queue and then on pressing positive button you need to dequeue the content you just have shown and then show the next one until the queue is empty.

Call `dialog.dismiss()` when no other content is left in your queue. This does not require implementing your own custom dialog. You can add an `onShowListener` to the `AlertDialog` where you can then override the `onClickListener` of the button.

```
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(v)
        .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) // Set to null. We override the onclick
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .create();

dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

        Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Show content and dequeue

                // Dismiss once all contents are shown 
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

As far as I could understand, you need to show `Dialog` with new content along with a new layout each time you create those. In that case, you might consider achieve this behaviour in several ways. I would suggest using a `LocalBroadcastManager`.

In your `Activity`, create a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it in your `onCreate` function.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...

  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "open-next-dialog".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("open-next-dialog"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "open-next-dialog" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    int layoutId = intent.getIntExtra("layout_id");
    showDialog(layoutId, message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now when a `Dialog` is clicked, you need to send a broadcast after dismissing the `Dialog`. So the `onClick` function of your `Dialog` will look like.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO: Do whatever you want to do in your onClick
    // And then Dismiss the dialog 
    dialog.dismiss();
    openNextDialogIfAny();
}
```

Don't forget to add `openNextDialogIfAny` function in your `Activity` as well which will trigger the next `Dialog`.

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "open-next-dialog". The Intent sent should be received by your Activity
private void openNextDialogIfAny() {
  if(messageStack.isEmpty()) return; // No more dialogs to be shown.

  Intent intent = new Intent("open-next-dialog");
  intent.putExtra("message", messageStack.pop());
  intent.putExtra("layout_id", layoutStack.pop());
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(YourActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: Idea i had as well, but the problem i ran into is that my dialogs all look and act different. So i would have to keep stuff like the dialog design and functions in my queue so i can create the custom dialogs when its their turn. I was more hoping that android provides a possibility to add dialogs to a stack which will be worked off until empty. But i guess not?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I hope you can pave your way of implementing it this time. Please let me know if you have any other issues. The code is not tested. Please modify according to your need. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but an easier answer has been provided which aims pretty exactly on what i had in mind.

Comment: using broadcasts for this is a terrible terrible idea. Broadcasts are not ment to do inter process (app) communication. Also they get restricted more and more with every Android version. Lot's of boiler plate code for handling a dialog, error prone.